# Get iPhone address book contacts into a mobile web app?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, cordova

Is it possible to get iPhone address book/contacts into a  mobile web app? Yes/No, how?

Comment: which framework of JavaScript you are using in your mobile apps ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no API in JavaScript to fetch the address book content in Mobile Web application **BUT** the  **PhoneGap** have made it available through the plugins So they have exposed the Phone Contact list through `Contact` JS class,

Follow the below link to play with phone Contact list .

[PhoneGap `Contact` Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html)

Comment: yes , it will and the supported Platforms are ...
1->Android
2->BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)
3->iOS

Comment: The [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html) has changed, just a litle.