# Is it possible to access a cell phone's contacts from a web app?

Tags: c#, android, ios, asp.net

Let's say I'm writing an web app that needs to be able to access the contacts in user's phone in order to perform a function, like finding other users of the web app. Similar in nature to how you can find other users of Snapchat on your phone just by letting snapchat access your contacts and march the phone numbers with other snapchat users. Is this possible in a web app? How could I go about implementing it?

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459754/get-iphone-address-book-contacts-into-a-mobile-web-app)

Answer (score 1):

Depends for example Windows phone store contacts on your live or hotmail account or android usually on gmail. So if the user login with this information on your site then you can.

1. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826530 for a microsoft example. for a wp example
2. see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1 for a gmail example.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create a phonegap application to publish the phone contact to server.

Answer (score 0):

Apple makes it pretty difficult now days to access any of the phones information(phone number, etc) from an app. You could make it possible in your app to manually get the contacts and then push them to your web app. Might get blocked from the apple store though for trying to do this. Here is an example for iOS

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    ...
}
```